# TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery.tmpl to create tables through ajax call.
Table row is coming from database .

And i included all the tablesorter plugins that is ,tablesorte,js,latest.js and css

But it is giving error as tablesorter is not a function...

```
$.ajax({
.....
  success:function(){
    $("#mytable").addClass("tablesorter");
    $("#mytable:has(tbody tr)").tablesorter();
  }
});
```

Comment: make sure tablesorter js is loaded..

Comment: make sure jquery isn't being loaded twice

Comment: Double check the path to the plugin and check for other js errors on the page

Comment: yes i checked all the possibilites.. It is loaded properly

Comment: can u explain question clearly

Comment: its working after removing latest.js